# Meta SE reputation

Tags: support, reputation, voting, meta, meta-reputation

Why is there an option of upvote downvote in Meta SE? It never affects my reputation.It neither increases not decreases reputation. Then why is it there?

Comment: Voting in meta is a way of showing (general) approval/disproval of the post. Very useful in gauging popularity of a point of view. I would be happier with it, if we could be sure that a representative sample of users visited meta to vote.

Comment: The purpose of votes isn't reputation. The purpose of votes is to determine what the community thinks of a particular post. It happens that on main, posts that are voted on are rewarded/sanctioned by reputation, but this isn't the case on meta. It doesn't mean votes are pointless, because they still fulfill their primary purpose: determining what the community thinks of a post.

Comment: @Najib: That comment should be an answer.

Comment: Among the links listed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-reputation/info) I found: [Why don't meta posts count towards rating (at least to some degree) on individual stackexchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244967/why-dont-meta-posts-count-towards-rating-at-least-to-some-degree-on-individua) This one seems related, too: [Why don't Meta upvotes count?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/why-dont-meta-upvotes-count) (You can probably find a few more related discussions.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The purpose of votes isn't reputation. The purpose of votes is to determine what the community thinks of a particular post. It happens that on main, posts that are voted on are rewarded/sanctioned by reputation, but this isn't the case on meta. It doesn't mean votes are pointless, because they still fulfill their primary purpose: determining what the community thinks of a post.

Comment: Made into an answer by popular request.